# RedirectToAction send object

Tags: c#, .net-core

I know there are similar questions but those questions are only passing a single value.

My problem is, attribute object is always null with  RedirectToAction() method.
But if I use int or string, I can pass the data to Error Method successfully.

If you look at the picture.

[image]

**If i use this code it is working.**

```
string error = "Test"
return RedirectToAction("Error2", "Home", new { errorMessage = error });
```

Error 2 gets error message `"Test"`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error2(string errorMessage)
{

    return View(new ErrorViewModel
    { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

**but if this is not working. message is *null*.**

```
ErrorViewModel error = new ErrorViewModel
{
    RequestId = "Home",
    ControllerName = "Home Controller",
    ActionName = "Index",
    ErrorMessage = "Error Message 1"
};

return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { errorMessage = error });
```

Error method's errorMessage everything is null.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error(ErrorViewModel errorMessage)
{
    log.Log(errorMessage);
    return View(new ErrorViewModel
    { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

Comment: Use `TempData` for complex types like that.

Comment: Thank you Nkosi. I am recording error log. I need this data for log.Log() method.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TempData` for complex types like that.

```
ErrorViewModel error = new ErrorViewModel {
    RequestId = "Home",
    ControllerName = "Home Controller",
    ActionName = "Index",
    ErrorMessage = "Error Message 1"
};

TempData["Message"] = error;

return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
```

and retrieve it within the target action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Error() {
    if (TempData["Message"] != null) {
        ErrorViewModel errorMessage = (ErrorViewModel) TempData["Message"];
        log.Log(errorMessage);    
    }

    return View(new ErrorViewModel
    { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new ErrorViewModel
        {
            RequestId = "Home",
            ControllerName = "Home Controller",
            ActionName = "Index",
            ErrorMessage = "Error Message 1"
        });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Error(ErrorViewModel error)
    {
        log.Log(error);
        return View(new ErrorViewModel
        { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```